MySQL connection error and PID error (Mac M1)
I have two issues when starting MySQL for the first time. I've tried changing permission level as stated in several advices on Google but never worked for me.
I've downloaded ARM version which is for Mac M1

Both through the Workbench and System settings, connection is not established.

Through Terminal,


mysql.server start

ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file

Thanks in advance

how is your question about robotics?
